# Android setImageResource causing application to crash

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-imageview

To start off I'm pretty new with android programming so this error may very well be something extremely simple I didn't notice. But whenever I open the simple app on my it starts with an image. When I swipe it's supposed to change to a different image but instead the app crashes. Any ideas why this is?

here is my java code

```
package example.course.bananapeeler;
import android.gesture.Gesture;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
        GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener{

    private ImageView mainPic;
    private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetector;
    private int moneyPerSecond;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this);
        gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);

        //ImageView mainPic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mainPic);
        ImageView mainPic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mainPic);
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent2, float v, float v2) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent2, float v, float v2) {
        /*
        ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
        findViewById(R.id.mainPic);
        */
        mainPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.peeledbanana);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        this.gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"><![CDATA[


/"peeledbanana";
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
]]>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mainPic"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/mainbanana"
    android:contentDescription="@string/mainPic" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Not sure why the format of the syntax file is strange. Is this causing the crashes?

Logcat Errors

> 05-13 17:16:47.329    2333-2333/example.course.bananapeeler
>   E/InputEventReceiver﹕ Exception dispatching input event. 05-13
>   17:16:47.329    2333-2333/example.course.bananapeeler
>   E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ Exception in MessageQueue callback:
>   handleReceiveCallback 05-13 17:16:47.339
>   2333-2333/example.course.bananapeeler E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object
>   reference
>               at example.course.bananapeeler.MainActivity.onFling(MainActivity.java:88)
>               at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:620)
>               at android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat$GestureDetectorCompatImplJellybeanMr2.onTouchEvent(GestureDetectorCompat.java:475)
>               at android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(GestureDetectorCompat.java:538)
>               at example.course.bananapeeler.MainActivity.onTouchEvent(MainActivity.java:102)
>               at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2869)
>               at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2529)
>               at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9180)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4734)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4572)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4149)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4115)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4229)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4123)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4286)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4149)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4115)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4123)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6600)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6484)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6455)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6690)
>               at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
>               at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>               at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183) 05-13
>   17:16:47.339    2333-2333/example.course.bananapeeler
>   D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM 05-13 17:16:47.339
>   2333-2333/example.course.bananapeeler E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: example.course.bananapeeler, PID: 2333
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object
>   reference
>               at example.course.bananapeeler.MainActivity.onFling(MainActivity.java:88)
>               at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:620)
>               at android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat$GestureDetectorCompatImplJellybeanMr2.onTouchEvent(GestureDetectorCompat.java:475)
>               at android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(GestureDetectorCompat.java:538)
>               at example.course.bananapeeler.MainActivity.onTouchEvent(MainActivity.java:102)
>               at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2869)
>               at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2529)
>               at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9180)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4734)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4572)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4149)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4115)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4229)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4123)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4286)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4149)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4115)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4123)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6600)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6484)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6455)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6690)
>               at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
>               at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>               at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)

Comment: What error do you have? Please post your logcat message.

Comment: I added the logcat but I'm not sure how to give it the right format. I'm sorry but I hope this will provide more information on my error

Answer (score 3):

You're initializing mainPic locally instead of the class variable.

Change

```
ImageView mainPic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mainPic);
```

to

```
mainPic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mainPic);
```

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that before and it didn't work but now it did so thank you for the help!